# write a javascript var="some text" into a pre loaded but empty txt document

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm creating a dynamic playlist for a music player I've put together. The playlist is going to sit in an external .txt document. I'll use an example. I have a variable:

```
playlist="track_1"
```

on the page is a button

```
<button onclick="add_track()">
```

in the script in the head

```
function add_track()
  {
  playlist=playlist+" track_2"
     ...What I need here is some way to put the playlist variable into a txt doc
  }
```

The buttons will be generated by php to include the name of the track to add to the playlist variable string. Document.write is perfect for this function as it replaces everything with the content of the variable; unfortunately it replaces the document the button is in not an specified external file.

Comment: What do you mean by text document in a browser context? Do you want to create a text file on the users computer? You can't open an empty document, but you make the user download text you prepared.

Comment: Do you want to use the text-file as persistent storage of the tracks on the server? Then you'll have to write a server-side procedure that manages this file, e.g. a php-script. Then you could use ajax to call this script and pass the track-name to the server.

Comment: You really should provide more information about your scenario and what you are trying to do. The more information you provide, the better answers we can give.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could create a JSON object in a file and save it as file1.json

```
{ "playlist" : "track1" }
```

and the use

```
$.getJSON("file1.json", function(data){
   var playlist=data.playlist+" track_2"
});
```

of course this works only when you read it, to write to the .json file you should use PHP or whatever you use server side

Answer (score 2):

You cannot write anything on a file with javascript. You'll need a server side solution.

Eg: You could have an ajax call to a php script that writes something in a txt file

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PHP to write/append into files. You can use [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function to call a PHP script to write/append into file:

```
jQuery('#buttonId').live('click',function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'write-file.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 
           playlist: "track_1"
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            for(var id in data) {
                alert( data[id] );
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

**write-file.php** *(something like this)*

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
fwrite($fh, $_POST['playlist']);
fclose($fh);

// echo status here in json format
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want write the playlist on the client side you can use the html5 filesystem api.
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: This will create a virtual filesystem for this website. This might or might not be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you actually want to do, you could open a new browser window with a [`data` URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/data_URIs), containing your text:

```
window.open('data:,' + encodeURIComponent(playlist));
```

The user only has to save the document then. The size of playlist ist limited by the allowed URI length though.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/UjzsG/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, first time I've asked a stupid question and got a really good answer. Turns out I'm a bit thick, don't need the PHP now but I will later when I want to save a playlist. Realised to make a dynamic playlist I can keep the array it lives in as a string in a variable, add tracks to the string then call eval(playlist) in each function that reads the list.

```
var playlist = 'var tracks = new Array("track_00","track_01"';
var end_bit = ');';
var playlist_full = playlist+end_bit;
```

Then to add stuff

```
function AddTrack()
{
playlist=playlist+'"track_02"';
}
```

And to read it

```
function ReadTrack()
{
playlist_full = playlist+end_bit;
eval(playlist_full)
document.getElementById("current_track").innerHTML=tracks[2];
}
```

Again cheers for all the advice.